# rails link path and routing error when model singular and plural name are the same (e.g. equipment, species)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")), new_equipment_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

I have the above code in a view, but am getting the following error when clicking the link: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"equipment"}`

My routes file contains:

```
resources :equipment

resources :workouts

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Why is it trying to access the show action?

Here are the entries from my routes:

```
   equipment_index GET        /equipment(.:format)                   equipment#index
                   POST       /equipment(.:format)                   equipment#create
     new_equipment GET        /equipment/new(.:format)               equipment#new
    edit_equipment GET        /equipment/:id/edit(.:format)          equipment#edit
         equipment GET        /equipment/:id(.:format)               equipment#show
                   PUT        /equipment/:id(.:format)               equipment#update
                   DELETE     /equipment/:id(.:format)               equipment#destroy
```

Comment: I suspect your t() block is confusing things — does it work when you change that to a normal string?

Like:

`<%= link_to "testing...", new_equipment_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>`

Comment: Yeah it's doing the same thing for a normal link_to

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output of running `rake routes`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This issue has [cropped up before](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rails/237541)** and is related to how rails scaffolding generates the new.html.erb file for models that have names like 'equipment' which are both singular and plural.

If you inspect the `form_for` in the new.html.erb file you'll see `equipment_path` in the link_to at the bottom.  For these models with singular==plural names that refers to a route that is actually for the `show` action, hence your error message.

The advice is often along the lines of 'avoid model names like this if you can' or it involves a bit of messing around with the config/initializers/inflections.rb file to force a plural version of the model name.  Of course then you end up with an app with very odd sounding references to models: 'equipments' isn't very nice to work with (and someone later on will 'fix' it, messing things up again).

To keep the model name grammatically correct, you need to fix the form_for i.e.:

`<% form_for(@equipment, :url=> {:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>`

and the link_to:

`<%= link_to 'Back', equipment_index_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an 's' to `equiment` in your **routes.rb**?

```
resources :equipments
```

Answer (score 0):

Since equipment is considered an uncountable noun, you should be able to solve this using inflections.

The rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) on inflections actually uses equipment as part of its' example.

Add the following to your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable 'equipment'
end
```

Additional information: [Uncountable Nouns in Rails 3 Resource Routing](http://markembling.info/2011/06/uncountable-nouns-rails-3-resource-routing)