# How to get fields from has_many :throught association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a many-to-many association throught  RoomsUsers model and in this model i have a role field, association works well but i can't access this field.
My schema looks like:

```
 create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.text "body"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer "user_id"
   t.integer "room_id"
 end                                                                       
 create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer "rooms_user_id"
 end
 create_table "rooms_users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer "user_id"
   t.integer "room_id"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.string "role"
   t.integer "last_checked"
 end
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "password_digest"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "mail"
  t.integer "rooms_user_id"
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password(validations: false)
  has_many :messages
  has_many :rooms_users
  has_many :rooms, through: :rooms_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms_users
  attr_accessor :register, :mail_confirmation, :login
end
```

Room model:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms_users
  has_many :users, through: :rooms_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms_users
  has_many :message
end
```

RoomsUsers model:

```
class RoomsUsers < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end
```

And i am trying to get role field from first user's room.

```
User.first.rooms.first.role
```

It give's me NoMethodError (undefined method `role' for #). What's wrong?

Comment: model name must be `RoomsUser` instead of `RoomsUsers` as per convention.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Ruby on Rails follow **linguistic convention**. That means a model represents a single user, whereas a database table consists of many users. So model name is singular & controller name is always plural.

Comment: I changed it and it still does not work.

Comment: It is not about working, it is about more than that. Code must be clean, readable, following convention and lots of things.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/21083020/10522579

Comment: Are you sure that your first user has any room? How did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `role` field in the `rooms` table, but it is in `rooms_users` table. Should be:

```
User.first.rooms_users.first.role
```

And remove `rooms_user_id` from `rooms` and `users` table, you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access "role" field through Rooms model, you will need to change the place of your "role" field from rooms_users table to rooms table. Doing it you can access "role" using `User.first.rooms.first.role`.

However if you want to keep "role" field in rooms_users table, so you will need to use `User.first.rooms_users.first.role` as [Vasilisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9269043/vasilisa) has already mentioned.

`t.integer "rooms_user_id"` are not necessary in rooms and users tables. The has_many used in rooms and users are already linking rooms_users with them.